# VBA Excel Paste on next row without information to shift if there is a blank cell copied

Tags: excel, vba

Hi everyone I am using this code to copy and paste information from one excel file to another. The problem is that some of the cells i copy have no data and the current code i use pastes the information on the next blank cell thus all of the information shifts. Does anyone know how i can fix that problem and paste the information on the next blank row.

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
   Range("F18").Copy
   emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
   ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 1), Cells(emptyRow, 19))
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
   Range("F14").Copy
   emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
   ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 2), Cells(emptyRow, 19))
```

Comment: Can you post or link to an example of what the destination sheet looks like when you use your existing code, and what you want it to look like? Are you running this code only once on your destination worksheet, or repeatedly using different source files?

Comment: @nekomatic i looping through different files, copying the cells and pasting them in a Range of cells in the destination file. The range is A1:G1. SO lets say i have copied data to A1:G1 BUT when copying the cell was blank which leaves me with cell C1 being blank. Then the program opens the next files, copies and pastes the information but (presumably it should do that in Range(A2:G2) but because i have cell C1 empty the data from the second file goes to G1 and the information shifts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paste the value from each new source sheet into the next row down on the destination, whether the source cell is blank or not, use a variable to keep track of your destination row:

```
' at the top of your code:
Dim destinationRow As Integer
destinationRow = 1

' ... start of your loop

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
   Range("F18").Copy
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
   ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(destinationRow, 1), Cells(emptyRow, 19))
   destinationRow = destinationRow + 1

' and so on
' ... end of your loop
```

I'm assuming that when you say you're 'looping through different files' you mean you're using some sort of loop in the VBA code that processes all the files. If you need to run a macro on separate occasions and always have the new data go to the end of the destination range you'll need to have your code save the value of `destinationRow` in a worksheet cell when it's finished, and read it in again next time it starts.